# How to combine different strings of text for each unique ID into 1 line for each ID

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

The image below shows the example table of data I have (columns A to B), and the table on the right (columns e to f) shows my desired output.

I just don't know where to start with this one, as I need to combine all the different DATA items together for each individual id.
Each ID is unique, but there can be any number of the same ID. The data can be replicated many times in the same ID and also include different data.

The data items will always be comma separated if more than 1 data item, and can be a mixture of numbers and letters of multiple lengths (even though my example shows single characters). The required data is what's always between each comma, where commas exist (i.e. except for single data items.)

The IDs are always numerical.

Therefore I'm struggling to come up with some VBA code for Excel 2010 (being a novice with VBA) to achieve this requirement. Any help would be very appreciated?

[image]

Comment: Please, show us what you trie by your own, even if it does not do what you need. Then, the data you show contains strings not "comma separated". They are *comma plus space separated". Is the shown separator always used in the existing data to be processed? I would suggest using a `Dictionary` and using its keys as unique IDs and an array as its items, containing all existing (unique) occurrences. Then, return them as a joined string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Combine Unique and Delimited Data Using a Dictionary of Dictionaries

```
Option Explicit

Sub CombineData()
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sDelimiter As String = ", "
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "E2"
    Const dDelimiter As String = ", "
    
    ' Source range to an array.
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    Dim rCount As Long
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sName).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        rCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        If rCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data or only headers
        Data = .Resize(rCount, 2).Offset(1).Value
    End With
    
    ' Array to a dictionary of dictionaries.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim Item As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    Dim n As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        Item = CStr(Data(r, 2))
        If Not IsError(Item) Then
            If Len(Item) > 0 Then
                Key = Data(r, 1)
                If Not IsError(Key) Then
                    If Len(Key) > 0 Then
                        Item = Split(Item, sDelimiter)
                        If Not dict.Exists(Key) Then
                            Set dict(Key) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                        End If
                        For n = 0 To UBound(Item)
                            dict(Key)(Item(n)) = Empty
                        Next n
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    rCount = dict.Count
    If rCount = 0 Then Exit Sub ' only error values or blanks
     
    ' Dictionary of dictionaries to the array.
    
    ReDim Data(1 To rCount, 1 To 2)
    r = 0
    
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        r = r + 1
        Data(r, 1) = Key
        Data(r, 2) = Join(dict(Key).Keys, dDelimiter)
    Next Key
    
    ' Array to the destination range.
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(dName).Range(dFirstCellAddress).Resize(, 2)
        .Resize(rCount).Value = Data
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row - rCount + 1).Offset(rCount).Clear
    End With

    MsgBox "Data combined.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Although all the examples are different and way beyond anything I cold have come up with. This one was the easiest one for me to understand as a novice in VBA., but I would like to thank you all for you help on this, as I really didn't think it would be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Please, use the next way. As I said in my comment, it uses a dictionary to extract the unique keys and other four arrays to keep intermediary values and build the final one. The following code is able to deal with both (possible) separators: comma "," and comma followed by one or more spaces ", ", ",  ", " ,". It works only in memory and should be very fast, even for large ranges:

```
 Sub extractUniqueIDsUniqueData()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrItem, arrIt, arrFin
   Dim i As Long, mtch, El, dict As Object
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   arr = sh.Range("A2:B" & lastR).value 'place the range in an array for faster iteration

   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   'fill the dictionary:
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
            arrItem = Split(Replace(arr(i, 2), " ", ""), ",") 'replace spaces before splitting
            dict.Add arr(i, 1), arrItem
        Else
            If arr(i, 2) <> "" Then  'skip the empty strings in B:B
                arrIt = Split(Replace(arr(i, 2), " ", ""), ",")
                arrItem = dict(arr(i, 1))
                If UBound(arrItem) = -1 Then 'if no any element in the item array
                    arrItem = arrIt                  'use the existing processed B:B value instead
                Else
                    For Each El In arrIt
                        mtch = Application.match(El, arrItem, 0)
                        If IsError(mtch) Then 'not existing in the item array
                            ReDim Preserve arrItem(UBound(arrItem) + 1)
                            arrItem(UBound(arrItem)) = El 'add the new element in the item array
                        End If
                    Next El
                End If
                dict(arr(i, 1)) = arrItem    'place the array back as dictionary item
            End If
        End If
   Next i
   
   'Process the dictionary content:
   ReDim arrFin(1 To dict.count + 1, 1 To 2) 'redim the array to keep all dictionary elements
   
   'fill the header in the final array:
   arrFin(1, 1) = "FinalList": arrFin(1, 2) = "Combined DATA"
   'fill the rest of the final array rows
   For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
        arrFin(i + 2, 1) = dict.Keys()(i)
        arrFin(i + 2, 2) = Join(dict.items()(i), ", ")
   Next i
   'drop the final array content at once:
   With sh.Range("E1").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2))
        .value = arrFin
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
   End With
   MsgBox "Ready..."
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This generates the combined output per the input data provided.  The code uses `Dictionaries` to assist in getting to the unique sets of values.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()

    Dim sourceWksht As Worksheet
    Set sourceWksht = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.("Sheet1")
    
    Dim rawData As Variant
    rawData = sourceWksht.Range("A2:B12").Value2
    
    Dim rawInputDictionary As Dictionary
    Set rawInputDictionary = New Dictionary
    
    Dim csvValue As String
    
    Dim rawIndex As Long
    For rawIndex = LBound(rawData, 1) To UBound(rawData, 1)
        csvValue = Trim$(rawData(rawIndex, 2))
        If Not rawInputDictionary.Exists(rawData(rawIndex, 1)) And Len(csvValue) > 0 Then
            rawInputDictionary.Add rawData(rawIndex, 1), csvValue
        ElseIf Len(csvValue) > 0 Then
            rawInputDictionary.Item(rawData(rawIndex, 1)) _
                = rawInputDictionary.Item(rawData(rawIndex, 1)) & "," & csvValue
        End If
    Next
    
    GenerateOutput rawInputDictionary, sourceWksht
    
End Sub

Private Sub GenerateOutput(ByVal rawInputDictionary As Dictionary, ByVal wksht As Worksheet)
    
    Dim outputArray As Variant
    ReDim outputArray(1 To rawInputDictionary.Count, 1 To 2)
    
    Dim outputArrayIndex As Long
    outputArrayIndex = 1
    
    Dim idKey As Variant
    For Each idKey In rawInputDictionary.Keys
        outputArray(outputArrayIndex, 1) = idKey
        outputArray(outputArrayIndex, 2) = GenerateCombinedData(rawInputDictionary.Item(idKey))
        outputArrayIndex = outputArrayIndex + 1
    Next
    
    Dim outputRange As Range
    Set outputRange = wksht.Range("E2:F" & CStr(rawInputDictionary.Count + 1))
    outputRange.Value = outputArray
End Sub

Private Function GenerateCombinedData(ByVal idValues As String) As String
    
    Dim combinedData As String
    combinedData = vbNullString
    
    Dim outputDictionary As Dictionary
    Set outputDictionary = New Dictionary
    
    Dim valuesArrayIndex As Long
    
    Dim valuesArray As Variant
    valuesArray = Split(idValues, ",")
    For valuesArrayIndex = LBound(valuesArray) To UBound(valuesArray)
        If Not outputDictionary.Exists(valuesArray(valuesArrayIndex)) Then
            combinedData = combinedData & valuesArray(valuesArrayIndex) & ","
            'Use the outputDictionary 'Keys' to ignore duplicate values
            outputDictionary.Add valuesArray(valuesArrayIndex), ""
        End If
    Next

    'Trim the trailing comma
    combinedData = Left$(combinedData, Len(combinedData) - 1)
    
    GenerateCombinedData = combinedData
End Function
```